# WebRTCDemo apk fetch wrong addresses from STUN/TURN server

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn

following http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android, the WebRTCDemo apk I built runs well on my android device and can start video calls with Chrome. the issue is 1) the apk failed to establish connections with peers when in different LANs, 2) but two Chromes can succeed to start p2p calls.

after checking the log I found the apk gives wrong candidate transport addresses. my private address is 10.10.10.108 and the public address is 112.10.45.196, the apk will send the following transport addresses to room server:

```
10.0.2.15
10.10.10.108
10.236.188.19
..ipv6..
```

so it is odd that where the apk learned these tow addresses:

```
10.0.2.15
10.236.188.19
```

after sniffing traffic using WireShark, I did not found any clue, the TURN/STURN server respond with correct values.

so anyone knows why?

Comment: What is the IP address of your STUN/TURN server that your Android code uses?  If your server is not on the public internet (and itself is behind the same NAT as you are), then you might get issues like this. btw, you say your private IP address is 10.10.10.108.  So where do you suppose those other IP addresses are coming from? (10.0.2.15 and 10.236.188.19)?

Comment: @selbie all servers, STUN/TURN server and room server, are running on AWS with a public address. I don't know where comes theses private IPs which is part of my question.

Comment: Your client is either failing to make the STUN binding and/or TURN allocate request. Or it's not making it at all.  Do a wireshark capture and look to see what the STUN/TURN requests are doing.

Comment: @selbie the STUN/TURN server return successful Allocate responses from my server but no Binding request/response. The client was built from WebRTC source code directly and I did not make any change.

Comment: The "server-reflexive" mapped address (equivalent to STUN binding response) should have been in the TURN allocate response.

Comment: @selbie after debugging I found the TURN allocation responses were discarded, so I commented out the integrity checking code and finally the apk successfully connects to device in another network.